# IPA characters in plain TeX

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, characters, linguistics, alphabet

Is there a way to type IPA characters in TeX? There is the [`tipa`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/tipa/) package for LaTeX, but what about plain TeX? I don't have any experience with installing fonts in TeX and can't find any good resource on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't realise that the font from that package could be used in plain TeX too (like `\font\ipafont=tipa12`).

Comment: You'll need also some macros for getting at the symbols, if you don't want to consult every time the font table. It's possible, by looking at `t3enc.def` and modifying it to make it compatible with Plain.

Comment: Actually, I hardly needed to consult the font table -- the font pretty much follows SAMPA. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8):

You could use XeTeX with a OpenType font which includes phonetic symbols. Example:

```
\font\sil="Charis SIL"
\sil
['tiːaıpıːeı 'taıpfeısız]
\bye
```

Compile with `xetex yourfilename.tex` (produces `yourfilename.pdf`)

Comment: Thanks, I guess that would work, but I don't really want to use XeTeX (I use macros that need pdfTeX)... Anyway, solved.